# How to sell ETH for USD or EUR?

Tags: ether, bitcoin, exchanges

What is the process to get Dollar or Euro from Ether to my bank account?

The easiest is to sell ETH into BTC on Poloniex, then I transfer my BTC to Kraken and on Kraken I sell BTC into Euro and the next step is withdraw Euro to my bank account?

Is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kraken has ETH/EUR market with quite a nice liquidity, you could use them straight without needing to go through BTC in between.

Comment: They closed registrations several days ago, I hear.